# Screw for concrete roof

Tags: concrete, roof, screws, anchor

I am installing some solar panels that measure 41" x 27" on my concrete flat roof using slotted angle bars. What type of of screws (as well as wish and length) would be best to attach to the roof and permit the best shear strength for hurricane force winds. I have a lot of 1/4 inch width Tapcon anchor screws. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Well tapcons would work but the panel size is needed to calculate the what withdrawal force is needed. Then it goes to the length and width of the screw as you know. On the panels I have installed they have requirements for different zones.

Comment: If you seal around the edges of the panels to the roof then the wind won’t get under the panels which helps...

Comment: If you are in a hurricane prone area, chances are building codes specify exactly what types of fasteners and other construction methods are required. Start by asking your building inspector.

Comment: What is a "concrete roof", exactly? Pre-cast? Poured? Something else?

Comment: @isherwood I guess it's rebar with poured concrete

Comment: @EdBeal I will attach the slotted angle bars on both sides which is about 3 feet long. Thinking of putting in 2 or 3 anchor screws. The maximum slotted holes width of the bar is 5/8.

Comment: rick that sounds light to me for screws I live in the Pacific Northwest and a full sized panel here would require more screws , sleeved anchors are actually better as @soler mentions. And may provide enough withdrawal force , since you are in a high wind area the size of the panel itself is needed. As I and others have mentioned there usually are minimum requirements.  + for Solers answer.

Answer (score 4):

I used sleeve masonry anchors for my solar panels.

[image]

Screws will not work well with concrete. Solar panels act like a sail in the wind, do not underestimate the forces involved.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: These allow easy removal of whatever is bolted down as well; with tapcons, you'd eventually just strip the hole after removal.

Comment: There are specific types of screws that do work with concrete. We use Hilti's HUS-3 a fair bit.